# Is PHP @ safe for checking array values ?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm working on arrays or objects with many optional fields. I'm trying to check field values without getting a PHP error, which lead me to :

```
$name = isset($revision['data']['name']) ? $revision['data']['name']: null;
```

or (with Laravel)

```
$name = isset($revision->data->name) ? $revision->data->name: null;
$name = isset($revision->data->name) ? $revision->data->name : 'default';
```

Is it safe in this specific case to use :

```
$value = @ $revision['data']['name'];
$value = @ $revision['data']['name'] ?: 'default';
```

If not, what would be a nicer way to handle these values ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's safe in the sense that it will prevent errors from reporting, however I wouldn't say it is good practice. It's more explicit when you see `isset` over `@`, mostly because the code is telling me up front that it's checking for if the array index is set.

Another alternative is to use Laravel's `array_get` if you don't mind pulling in their helper functions. In this case, you'd have: `$name = (array_get($revision, 'data.name')) ?: null;` as Laravel's helper will return null automatically for unset indexes. You can also manually set a default value `array_get($array, 'foo.bar', 'default');`

Comment: The helper function seems great, and I can use the object_get() function as well. Thanks you !